# Get disks with specific size by Ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have `ansible_devices` variable in json format, and I want to get only some disks names list with specific size. I tried to use `json_query` with `filter` following [this howto](https://blog.networktocode.com/post/ansible-filtering-json-query/), but I can't get my data, variable `my_disks` is empty. But if i do not use `json_query` filter, it fills by json below.

```yaml
    - name: set facts
      vars:
        query_disks: "[?sectors==`7814037168`].dev"
      set_fact:
        my_disks: "{{ ansible_devices | json_query('[?sectors==`7814037168`]') }}"

    - name: print found disks with specific size 7814037168
      debug:
        msg:
          - my_disks "{{ my_disks }}"
```

JSON:

```json
{
"ansible_devices": {
    "dm-0": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [
                "dm-name-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv",
                "dm-uuid-LVM-JTbEQFwBnnRZ8qLNZZZJJSAfYxYnnbUyVJzynNhorlBulf0g1H2tTpVX8lPGGpdP"
            ],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": [
                "c634c808-d0fe-4579-a6fa-747b36ab6627"
            ]
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "",
        "sectors": "209715200",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "100.00 GB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop0": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "113896",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "55.61 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop1": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "113888",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "55.61 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop2": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "129672",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "63.32 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop3": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "129712",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "63.34 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop4": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "188072",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "91.83 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop5": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "188032",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "91.81 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop6": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "109032",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "53.24 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop7": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "109032",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "53.24 MB",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "loop8": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "",
        "links": {
            "ids": [],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": null,
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "none",
        "sectors": "0",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "0.00 Bytes",
        "support_discard": "4096",
        "vendor": null,
        "virtual": 1
    },
    "sda": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)",
        "links": {
            "ids": [
                "ata-MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422",
                "scsi-0ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422",
                "scsi-1ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422",
                "scsi-350014ee00320fd29",
                "scsi-SATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422",
                "wwn-0x50014ee00320fd29"
            ],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": "MB0500EBNCR",
        "partitions": {
            "sda1": {
                "holders": [],
                "links": {
                    "ids": [
                        "ata-MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part1",
                        "scsi-0ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part1",
                        "scsi-1ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part1",
                        "scsi-350014ee00320fd29-part1",
                        "scsi-SATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part1",
                        "wwn-0x50014ee00320fd29-part1"
                    ],
                    "labels": [],
                    "masters": [],
                    "uuids": []
                },
                "sectors": "2048",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "1.00 MB",
                "start": "2048",
                "uuid": null
            },
            "sda2": {
                "holders": [],
                "links": {
                    "ids": [
                        "ata-MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part2",
                        "scsi-0ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part2",
                        "scsi-1ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part2",
                        "scsi-350014ee00320fd29-part2",
                        "scsi-SATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part2",
                        "wwn-0x50014ee00320fd29-part2"
                    ],
                    "labels": [],
                    "masters": [],
                    "uuids": [
                        "b56a8fd9-dcb6-4861-be97-fbc0e2d35261"
                    ]
                },
                "sectors": "2097152",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "1.00 GB",
                "start": "4096",
                "uuid": "b56a8fd9-dcb6-4861-be97-fbc0e2d35261"
            },
            "sda3": {
                "holders": [
                    "ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv"
                ],
                "links": {
                    "ids": [
                        "ata-MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part3",
                        "lvm-pv-uuid-zczj1C-x1rv-e5KW-a9MJ-F3cn-Uidi-jF2OZb",
                        "scsi-0ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part3",
                        "scsi-1ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part3",
                        "scsi-350014ee00320fd29-part3",
                        "scsi-SATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3116422-part3",
                        "wwn-0x50014ee00320fd29-part3"
                    ],
                    "labels": [],
                    "masters": [
                        "dm-0"
                    ],
                    "uuids": []
                },
                "sectors": "974669824",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "464.76 GB",
                "start": "2101248",
                "uuid": null
            }
        },
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "mq-deadline",
        "sectors": "976773168",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "465.76 GB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": "ATA",
        "virtual": 1,
        "wwn": "0x50014ee00320fd29"
    },
    "sdb": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)",
        "model": "ST4000VX013-2XG1",
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "mq-deadline",
        "sectors": "7814037168",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "3.64 TB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": "ATA",
        "virtual": 1,
        "wwn": "0x5000c500e04f7ede"
    },
    "sdc": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)",
        "links": {
            "ids": [
                "ata-MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198",
                "scsi-0ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198",
                "scsi-1ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198",
                "scsi-350014ee05876512e",
                "scsi-SATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198",
                "wwn-0x50014ee05876512e"
            ],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": "MB0500EBNCR",
        "partitions": {
            "sdc2": {
                "holders": [],
                "links": {
                    "ids": [
                        "ata-MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198-part2",
                        "scsi-0ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198-part2",
                        "scsi-1ATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198-part2",
                        "scsi-350014ee05876512e-part2",
                        "scsi-SATA_MB0500EBNCR_WMAYP3118198-part2",
                        "wwn-0x50014ee05876512e-part2"
                    ],
                    "labels": [],
                    "masters": [],
                    "uuids": []
                },
                "sectors": "5254202",
                "sectorsize": 512,
                "size": "2.51 GB",
                "start": "16255488",
                "uuid": null
            }
        },
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "mq-deadline",
        "sectors": "976773168",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "465.76 GB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": "ATA",
        "virtual": 1,
        "wwn": "0x50014ee05876512e"
    },
    "sdd": {
        "holders": [],
        "host": "IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)",
        "links": {
            "ids": [
                "ata-ST4000VX013-2XG104_WFN6EZDR",
                "scsi-0ATA_ST4000VX013-2XG1_WFN6EZDR",
                "scsi-1ATA_ST4000VX013-2XG104_WFN6EZDR",
                "scsi-35000c500e04f9132",
                "scsi-SATA_ST4000VX013-2XG1_WFN6EZDR",
                "wwn-0x5000c500e04f9132"
            ],
            "labels": [],
            "masters": [],
            "uuids": []
        },
        "model": "ST4000VX013-2XG1",
        "partitions": {},
        "removable": "0",
        "rotational": "1",
        "sas_address": null,
        "sas_device_handle": null,
        "scheduler_mode": "mq-deadline",
        "sectors": "7814037168",
        "sectorsize": "512",
        "size": "3.64 TB",
        "support_discard": "0",
        "vendor": "ATA",
        "virtual": 1,
        "wwn": "0x5000c500e04f9132"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `but I can't get my data` (which is a synonym of `it doesn't work`) [is not an accurate description of your problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What is the result/error you get? Please don't answer in comments, [edit] your question with a [mre]

Comment: Meanwhile, as a simple test, storing your above data as-is in `data.json` and issuing `ansible localhost -e @data.json -m debug -a "msg={{ ansible_devices | dict2items | selectattr('value.sectors', '==', '7814037168') | items2dict }}"` gives the expected result (i.e. returns details for `sdb` and `sdd`)

Comment: i get error with your example:localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ ansible_devices | dict2items | selectattr('value.sectors', '==', '7814037168') | items2dict }}): items2dict requires a list, got <class 'generator'> instead."
}

Comment: From my first comment: `Please don't answer in comments, edit your question with a minimal reproducible example`

Answer (score -2):

I found other [solution](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/automating-storage-management-rhel-system-roles):

```
    - name: set facts
      set_fact:
       my_disks: "{{ ansible_devices | dict2items | selectattr('key', 'match', '^sd.*') | rejectattr('key', 'match', '^sda$') | selectattr('value.size', 'match', '^3.64 TB') | map(attribute='key') | list }}"
```

```
ok: [server] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "my_disks": [
            "sdd",
            "sdb"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the answer and make clear how this is answering the original problem (i.e. selecting disks having 7814037168 sectors)